# Text Direction in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report to Print an Expression Containing One English word between Two Persian words. Picture below demonstrate the correct form of my Expression.

[image]

when I save the Expression in Sql Data base the result will be as follow :

[image]

As you see my expression has been Reversed in a wrong way and will be shown wrong in crystal report.

Is there any way  to prevent Crystal Report from Reversing?

Answer (score 1):

Set Text Direction Right to left to Textbox in crystal report

Comment: Text Direction? where is Text Direction?

Comment: Check for right aligned format to your text object, if its not there make sure you are using SP5 http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824